# Get Menu Items in Custom Module

Tags: routes, blocks

I'm creating a custom module block that will sit in the sidebar on certain levels of my site template.

The site structure is: Home > Level 1 > Level 2 > Article.

I want Level 2 to echo out all of the child links (basically a menu tree).

I want to achieve this with `hook_block_view()`. How can I get the page's child links in the main menu, and put them in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block)?

> provides configurable blocks of menu trees starting with any level of any menu.

It does exactly what you're looking for. If you still want to write a custom module I reckon looking through the code for that module would be the best place to start.